# Paging is not worked by default in Jboss 7.2

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I have application is deployed on Jboss EAP 7.2 and some queues. In official documentation we have - *JBoss EAP messaging paging is enabled by default.*

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html-single/configuring_messaging/index#configuring_paging

But when i loaded my ActiveMq queues i do not has any information in default directory for paging: **/EAP-7.2\standalone\data\activemq*

**My questions:**

1. When i configured  for setting paging mode kind of name me need to set for address-setting name? - name as `<jms-queue>` which queue i want config or something else?
2. Why i don't have paging directory and ActiveMq not used paging by default?

**I tried:**

1. Create address-setting with name `<jms-queue>` and change pattern to `address-full-policy = BLOCK` but my queue still accumulate message without control
2. Tried same for name IBM MQ queue name which worked with my ActiveMq queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuration "Paging" you need:

1. Create "address-setting" with full name of your jms-queue. In standalone.xml i have:

> <jms-queue name="test-queue" .....

You can see full name also in GUI just find on: Runtime -> Server -> Messaging(ActiveMq) -> default -> Destination -> You queue name -> Queue Address

command for create "address-setting":

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/address-setting=jms.queue.test-queue/:add()
```

2. Folder for paging (activemq/paging) would be created by default if addres-policy in address-setting  = PAGE and *max-size-bytes* > -1 for your jms-queue. You need change default settings *max-size-bytes* and *page-size-bytes* for your situation.